# Get rowdata as bound to the gridview datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource, row

My GridView is bound to a certain DataSource. Each row only shows 4 of the 8 possible items.
Lets say we have name, adress, phone, fax, email, country, province and age.
The GridView would only show name, email, country and age, but I want to access the province and adress bound to a row.
How is this possible?

I got a custom GridView, with an onclick event which updates an panel (through AJAX) which shows additional information about the selected row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to another control (FormView, DetailView) that will show detailed info. It has be bound to DataSource as well and it should take Gridview.SelectedRow for input parameter.

Its called master/detail. Google it and you will find a lot of step by step tutorials.